# how to install proshow program on ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, productivity

- How to install a program **ProShow** on the Ubuntu system ?

Comment: Can you please provide some more information about what ProShow is? As stated this is a little unclear and not useful.

Comment: Program to edit videos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible natively and even Wine doesn't make it work. You need to find alternatives or deal without it.

Comment: What are the alternatives for this program!

Comment: Typing into google "alternatives proshow linux" yielded me this good result from [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/proshow/?platform=linux). For a simple slide show from a command line I've used feh successfully.